# cdn doesn't work in jquery

Tags: jquery

i create registration page in php with jquery validation.i am using CDN(content delivery network) for excute jquery .when i run program it's doesn't work validation part(jquery part)if i am click submit button page will redirect next page.jquery doesn't validate.what is reason for? answer me
my code is here

```
<html>
    <head><title>sign up</title> 
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#signup").validate({
                rules:
                    {
                    name : "required",
                    username :"required",
                   password : {required : true,minlength : 5,maxlength :10},
                    rpassword : 
                        {
                        required : true,
                        equalTo : "#password"
                        },
                   email_id: {required: true,email: true}
                    },
             messages:
                {
              name : "please provide your name",
              username : "please provide your username",
              password : {required : "please enter your password",minlenth : "your password must be atleast  5 character ",maxlength : "your password must be with in 10 character"},
              rpassword : {required : "please enter your confirmation password", equalTo : "Enter Retype Password Same as Password"},
              email_id: {required : "please enter e-mail id" ,email:"Please enter valid email"}
                },
                  submitHandler : function(form)
                  {
                   submitHandlerform.submit();   
                  }
               });
            });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="signup" action="signup.php" method="post" >
            <h1> REGISTRATION </h1>
            <table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <h2><b>full name</td></h2>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="name"></b></tr>
            <tr>
<td align="right">
    <h2> <b>username</td></h2>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" ></b></tr>
<td align="right">
       <h2> <b>password</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" ></b></td>
<tr>
<td align="right">
       <h2> <b>confirmation password</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="rpassword" ></b></td>

    </tr>        
    <td align="right"><h2><b>email id</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="email_id" ></b></td></h2>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit"> </td>    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        you have already account click <a href="index.php">here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't come with mehtod validate

Comment: i think you need to include the jquery validate plugin script. `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: jQuery validate page states that it is not tested with so old jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Its working:

```
<html>
    <head><title>sign up</title> 
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
            //$('#signup').submit( function(){
              $("#signup").validate({
      rules:
          {
          name : "required",
          username :"required",
        password : {required : true,minlength : 5,maxlength :10},
          rpassword : 
              {
              required : true,
              equalTo : "#password"
              },
        email_id: {required: true,email: true}
          },
              messages:
      {
    name : "please provide your name",
    username : "please provide your username",
    password : {required : "please enter your password",minlenth : "your password must be atleast  5 character ",maxlength : "your password must be with in 10 character"},
    rpassword : {required : "please enter your confirmation password", equalTo : "Enter Retype Password Same as Password"},
    email_id: {required : "please enter e-mail id" ,email:"Please enter valid email"}
      },
        submitHandler : function(form)
        {
        submitHandlerform.submit();   
        }
    });
            //});
          });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="signup" action="signup.php" method="post" >
            <h1> REGISTRATION </h1>
            <table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <h2><b>full name</td></h2>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="name"></b></tr>
            <tr>
<td align="right">
    <h2> <b>username</td></h2>
            <td align="left"><input type="text" name="username" ></b></tr>
<td align="right">
       <h2> <b>password</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="password" id="password" ></b></td>
<tr>
<td align="right">
       <h2> <b>confirmation password</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="password" name="rpassword" ></b></td>

    </tr>        
    <td align="right"><h2><b>email id</td></h2>
<td align="left"><input type="text" name="email_id" ></b></td></h2>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit"> </td>    </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        you have already account click <a href="index.php">here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why use these code why my code not working plz answer me

Comment: Your cdn link is not a valid one. And also in order to use jquery validate() need to include its js library.

Comment: what is purpose first line?give some explanation?

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    i specify these line

Comment: In order to use jquery functions we need to include its cdn link.
$(document).ready() is a jquery function. Normal js doesn't have this. If the code which I have provided is working for you then can you click the answer is helpful up button.

Answer (score 1):

Add validate plugin under jquery like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

For your information jquery validate plugin works with jquery 1.6. so update your jquery

Comment: why use these code why my code not working plz answer me

Comment: @manisankar. we are trying to provide solution for you. for any how default jquery dont have validate function so you have to include validate plugin. Above your code shows you are not included  jquery validate plugin. so we suggest you to add this in your code.

Comment: ok thank you for information.which code validate form first line or second line.if second line validate jquery what is purpose of first line plz answer me

Comment: pls understand both needed first jquery and then jqueryvalidate plugin.

Comment: jquery is a javascript framework. so if we are going to use jquery functions means we need to call jquery[First line]. jquery plugins are written using jquery[2nd line]. plugin file doesnot have jquery code so without jquery file jquery plugin not work.